# Multiple 2TB MSDOS partitions or 1 larger GPT partition for volume group

Tags: partitioning, mdadm, gpt, parted, ms-dos

I have just expanded my 1+0 raid from a total of 2TB to 6TB.

When adding each of the new drives I partitioned them using parted to create GPT based partitions to cover the entire of each of the drives. As I was aware fdisk would not generate me >2TB partitions.

The RAID rebuilt as expected; however I am now struggling to get the raid to use all the new free space available. It can see it, it just will not resize to use it all. 
I believe the issue I am having is due to the original MDADM partition being MSDOS based and therefore I am unable to expand it to >2TB.

As far as I can see I have 2 options:
1. Generate 2 more additional MS-DOS based 2TB partitions on the MDADM drive and then add each of these into my volume group to give me the total 6TB.
2. Remove the original 2TB MS-DOS based partition and replace with a 6TB GPT partition.

The advantages of pt 1 is that I would lose no data (it is all backed up so it is not critical if it is removed) and therefore reduce the time spent rebuilding. Whilst the benefits of pt 2 would be easier management in the future with just a single partition.

Are all my assumptions correct here in what I am trying to achieve? And if so, are there other pro's or cons to each of the methodologies.